# How often should AJAX reload specific content on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout, reload

I'm constructing an app where users can insert their preferences in a table. It is possible to load an updated version of the table via AJAX. I would like to load these updated versions from time to time, so the users will see almost always the newest version of the table, without reloading the page by themself. My questions regarding that are:

- How often should the browser of the user request via AJAX a new version of the table?
- Is that a bad approach? Maybe users want to reload the page manually.

Thank you for any answer in advance. Let me know how I can improve my question.

Comment: Depend on your system. Create a button on your page, to toggle between automatic refresh / manual refresh. And let's say, the interval is 10 second. And write it to your page too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably do it anywhere between 5 and 15 seconds. It's not a bad approach, and you can add a "refresh" button for manual refreshing. If your server is shared or there's lots of traffic, you can increase the duration to 30 seconds.

**Note:** This answer is based on my experience with web apps and previously built applications and web sites. There are no set standards for this behaviour.

Comment: Where do these arbitrary numbers come from?I might as well post another answer saying "between 2 and 20 seconds".

Comment: @PeeHaa 2 seconds would be overkill for your server. Web chat applications have 5 seconds (or less depending on the underlying code), but a decent value would be anywhere between 5 and 15 seconds. Values are based on experience and previously built web applications.

Comment: No, chat applications use websockets.

Comment: Not all of them. I was going to say, I see you wrote several applications, why don't you weigh in with your opinion. Clearly, the question is based on each user's experience. There are no set standards for this behaviour.

Comment: " There are no set standards for this behaviour" that is why questions like these cannot be correctly answered. The only person who could answer this would be the person who has all the relevant information and requirements. Being OP

Comment: I agree, but the OP doesn't know. It could probably be his/her first web application. I also agree with opinion-based questions, not being relevant. But I've been there, so I thought I might as well help.